# How to send data from datagram socket in Android to Node js Server?

Tags: android, node.js, udp, datagram

I try to program an online game for android. My first step is to establish a connection
between the client/the android application and the server. 
The server runs on Node js.

First I try to send data from the client to the server via my local network. 
The problem is that even such an easy thing does not work somehow. The server
is not able to receive any data from the client.

The Client:

```
public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        String messageStr = "Hallo Welt";

        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress local = null;
        local = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        int msg_length = messageStr.length();
        byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length, local, 12345);
        s.send(p);
        android.util.Log.w("UDP", "Works fine!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.err.println("ERROR!                               !");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;

}
```

The Server:

```js
'use strict';

var PORT = 12345;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port + ' - ' + message);
});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

What do i disregard here?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
server.bind(PORT);
```

instead. I try with another client. but before I change the server side, it didn't work. so I'm not sure with your client side